# Acumatica pivot tables not loading

Tags: customization, acumatica

I am trying to build a pivot table in acumatica Build 17.201.0043 sandbox to do some testing. 
When I View Pivot it keeps loading and the request times out as below

[image]

The GI for the pivot table is

[image: GI]

The Pivot table is...

[image: Pivot table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the SalesDemo database? Can you include screenshots from your Pivot Table definition?

Comment: I am trying to create a 12 month rolling report using the pivot table. Included the screenshot of pivot table definition.

Comment: Are there a lot of records in the Generic Inquiry that this Pivot Table is built on?

You might try creating a shared filter on the generic inquiry that drastically limits the number of records returned, then choose the shared filter in the "Shared Filter to Apply" field on your Pivot Table definition.

Comment: It worked after applying shared filters to the pivot table definition.
Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it. I think there is a way to increase the timeout using the web.config file, but if the Shared Filter works, I would just leave it at that.